# Migrating from Dagger 2 to Hilt with TestApplication and custom test Component

Tags: dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I am migrating a quite extensive app with many instrumented tests in it.

The way the app is structured is:

```
// in the main sources
open class MainApp {
    open val appComponent: ApplicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.factory...
}

// in the test sources
class TestApp: MainApp {
    override val appComponent: ApplicationComponent = DaggerTestApplicationComponent.factory...
}
```

and of course `TestApplicationComponent` implements `ApplicationComponent`.

The main component had a lot of sub-modules, and by following the guide on how to migrate the app by creating an aggregator entry point, everything compiles and works more than fine.

The missing piece is the `TestApp`, and that is the main subject of this issue. Is there a way to migrate (partially) the `TestApp` so that I simply can run the tests as they were, and in future I will migrate it to use either `CustomTestApplication` or `HiltTestApplication`?

As an initial stage of our migration, I don't need `@HiltAndroidTest` to be usable: I just need the old tests to be runnable like they were on Dagger 2.

This question has been raised also as an issue at https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2757.

Comment: hey @Alex Facciorusso, since this question was almost a year old, wondering if you were able to figure a way to gradually migrating to Hilt Tests?